# broadcast views irregularly numpy

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Assuming I want have a numpy array of size `(n,m)` where `n` is very large, but with a lot of duplication, ie. `0:n1` are identical, `n1:n2` are identical etc. (with `n2%n1!=0`, ie not regular intervals). Is there a way to store only one set of values for each of the duplicates while having a view of the entire array?

example:

```
unique_values = np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2] ,[3,3,3]]) #these are the values i want to store in memory
index_mapping = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,2,2]) # a mapping between index of array above, with array below

unique_values_view = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2], [3,3,3],[3,3,3]]) #this is how I want the view to look like for broadcasting reasons
```

I plan to multiply array(view) by some other array of size `(1,m)`, and take the dot product of this product:

```
other_array1 = np.arange(unique_values.shape[1]).reshape(1,-1) # (1,m)
other_array2 = 2*np.ones((unique_values.shape[1],1)) # (m,1)
output = np.dot(unique_values_view * other_array1, other_array2).squeeze()
```

Output is a 1D array of length `n`.

Comment: How do you plan to use the output? FYI : A view at the first stage, doesn't guarantee that there won't be forced-copy later on.

Comment: @Divakar True. I plan to multiply with another array of shape `(1,m)`, then storing the dot product with another array. The main consideration is fitting the array into memory. I could do the last step in chunks if it copying is enforced

Comment: Could you add mcve for the entire process, i.e. sample for that (1,m) array and then the final desired output?

Comment: That multiplication with `2` doesn't seem like a generic operation. Could you explain its significance?

Comment: Or could add a bit more generic minimal sample, say `index_mapping` with bigger range of numbers and `unique_values` with random numbers?

Comment: By "identical" do you mean they are integers?  Or just very close floats? (i.e can you do bitwise equvalence)

Comment: @DanielF If you look at `unique_values_view`, the zeroth and first inner list/array are both from `unique_values[0]`, the second, third and fourth are from `unique_values[1]` etc. The values will typically be floats, but I don't see how the type would matter. I want to duplicate array subsets into one large array, which doesn't store copies of all the duplicates.

Comment: @Divakar If you are able to show a solution to this minimal example, I will upvote it. If you can show that it doesn't require significantly more memory than `unique_values` using some kind of memory profiling, I will accept it right away.

Comment: @M.T Yakym Pirozhenko 's soln seem to work for the listed minimal case. But again, I can't see what would be the generic case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression admits two significant optimizations:

- do the indexing last
- multiply `other_array1` with `other_array2` first and then with
   `unique_values`

Let's apply these optimizations:

```
>>> output_pp = (unique_values @ (other_array1.ravel() * other_array2.ravel()))[index_mapping]

# check for correctness
>>> (output == output_pp).all()
True

# and compare it to @Yakym Pirozhenko's approach
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> print("yp:", timeit("np.dot(unique_values * other_array1, other_array2).squeeze()[index_mapping]", globals=globals()))
yp: 3.9105667411349714
>>> print("pp:", timeit("(unique_values @ (other_array1.ravel() * other_array2.ravel()))[index_mapping]", globals=globals()))
pp: 2.2684884609188884
```

These optimizations are easy to spot if we observe two things:

(1) if `A` is an `mxn`-matrix and `b` is an `n`-vector then

```
A * b == A @ diag(b)
A.T * b[:, None] == diag(b) @ A.T
```

(2) if `A` is an`mxn`-matrix and `I` is a `k`-vector of integers from
       `range(m)` then

```
A[I] == onehot(I) @ A
```

`onehot` can be defined as

```
def onehot(I, m, dtype=int):
    out = np.zeros((I.size, m), dtype=dtype)
    out[np.arange(I.size), I] = 1
    return out
```

Using these facts and abbreviating `uv`, `im`, `oa1` and `oa2` we can write

```
uv[im] * oa1 @ oa2 == onehot(im) @ uv @ diag(oa1) @ oa2
```

The above optimizations are now simply a matter of choosing the best order for these matrix multiplications which is

```
onehot(im) @ (uv @ (diag(oa1) @ oa2))
```

Using (1) and (2) backwards on this we obtain the optimized expression from the beginning of this post.

Answer (score 6):

Based on your example, you can simply factor the index mapping through the computation to the very end:

```
output2 = np.dot(unique_values * other_array1, other_array2).squeeze()[index_mapping]

assert (output == output2).all()
```